# How to specify input_type of a widget upon declaration?

Tags: django

Usually when defining a DateInput widget in the form, the generated html looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="from_date" id="id_from_date">
```

the type is `text` instead of `date` or `datetime`.

One way to fix this is, would be setting the type in the `__init__` :

```
class FilterCallsForm(Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FilterCallsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['from_date'].widget.input_type = 'date'

    from_date   = forms.DateField(localize=True, widget=forms.DateInput())
```

This works and I get a `<input type="date" name="from_date" id="id_from_date">` as required.

However is there a way to define it right when I declare the widget? I didn't find a way other than doing it through `__init__` which seems a bit odd.

Comment: This is fine. __init__ can be used for runtime modifications. However, the best practice would be to create a widget

Comment: thanks for your comment. Could you give me a tiny example what you mean by creating a widget? Do you mean extending forms.DateInput()?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/  You can create custom form widgets and specify it the way you want it to be rendered.

Comment: This is something i havent tried - in a form definition, can you specify {attrs = "type: date"}

Comment: oh yeah I have tried `{attrs = "type: date"}` without any luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subclass `DateInput`, and use your custom widget when you define the form:

```
class MyDateInput(DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class FilterCallsForm(Form):
    from_date = forms.DateField(localize=True, widget=MyDateInput())
```